How to efficiently check for duplicate URLs in a large MySQL database?
Currently, I’m working on a project where I store news article data in a MySQL database. The data I store includes the article title and its URL, with the URL set as the PRIMARY KEY to prevent duplicates.
The process works like this:
Before inserting a new article, I check if the URL already exists in the database.
If the URL doesn’t exist, I insert the new article into the database.
This works fine on a small scale, but I’m wondering how to handle this efficiently when the database grows to hundreds of millions or even billions of records.
Specifically, I’d like to know:
What is the most efficient way to check for duplicate URLs in a large MySQL database?
Does using the PRIMARY KEY for this kind of lookup perform well at such a large scale?
Are there any optimization techniques, indexing strategies, or alternative approaches I should consider?
Any advice on database design, MySQL-specific optimizations, or related technologies that could help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Primary keys are good approach, but if you are working with full urls, then it would not help much, and as far as I know, for columns like TEXT and LONGTEXT, MySQL doesn't allow primary keys. So, for that you can use short urls or things like that and then use primary keys along with it.

Consider splitting the url and indexing on the parts. But would you not want to search for articles on topics?

You can also make it easier for yourself. Save the URL wherever you want and generate an MD5 KEY from this string and save this key in its own field. This can also be done with a virtual field, so you only have to save the link and the MD5 value changes automatically. Don't forget INDEX!!. If you are now looking for a URL, you only need to generate the MD5 from the URL and can therefore search very effectively

with the URL set as the PRIMARY KEY to prevent duplicates Long string as primary key? This is very bad idea.. use synthetic PK and regular unique index. Moreover, I'd recommend you to add checksum(url) column (with URL normalizing) and use it for duplicate checking in the trigger logic instead of the index.

@VanshPatel Thank you for your insight! I agree that using long strings as primary keys can be inefficient. I’ll consider using a unique index with shorter keys, such as MD5 or a hash of the URL.

I’ll consider using a unique index with shorter keys, such as MD5 or a hash of the URL. This is bad idea. Of course the probability that the hash values for two different values will be equal is too low - but it is not zero. Additionally - do not forget to normalize your URLs (://site/page?a=1&b=2 and ://site/page?b=2&a=1 and ://site/page?A=1&b=02 and ..)
